# How to reduce the memory consumption of CUDA init in PyTorch?

Tags: memory, pytorch, out-of-memory, nvidia-jetson

I am using PyTorch on NVIDIA Jetson TX2 **(GPU and CPU have shared memory)**, and have only about 2 Gb of free memory.

Specifications:

- PyTorch v1.10.0
- JetPack 4.6.1
- CUDA 10.2

Whenever I try to use GPU, "torch.cuda.init()" would consume about 2Gb of memory.
If I use only the CPU, the memory overhead would be only 180 Mb of memory.

I have been searching the net and found that the reason is a load of kernels.
I understand that a lot of kernels are used for optimal computing, however, I can not even use my GPU due to it.
Also, I think that the overwhelming majority of kernels would be never used by me.

Could you please say how to reduce the memory overhead if I am willing to sacrifice the performance as long as I could use GPU?

Would it be possible to reduce it to the CUDA bare minimum? If it is possible, how to accomplish it?

I am trying to **train** the relatively small model with Conv2D, Pooling, and Dense layers.

At least how to reduce the memory overhead, so I could train simple models with only Dense layers?

**I also can not switch to other libraries due to other reasons.**

Comment: The docs for `torch.cuda.init()` says "Ordinary users should not need this, as all of PyTorch’s CUDA methods automatically initialize CUDA state on-demand." Have you tried not calling that function and just train your small model?

Comment: Yes, but it still takes 2 Gb

Comment: What is your batch size? Have you tried reducing it?

Comment: I used torch.rand(3,3).to("cuda")

Comment: So a single 3x3 float tensor takes 2GB GPU memory? That seems excessive. How did you get that 2GB?

Comment: If I initialize in CPU, it will take only 180 Mb of space.